# Java Completable future thread are alive after method execute

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future, forkjoinpool

I have written a small program to check behavior of Completable Future. I have not overridden the common pool.

I did not found any shut down method and when i print active number of thread at the end, i found my thread active.

My question is when they will end, if i am using it in life application?
And do they create to many thread if i use it in public Api, who have much traffic?

My samlple code

`

```
package rar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Rar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rar r = new Rar();
        
        
          Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
          System.out.println(threadSet); r.dfo(); threadSet =
          Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet(); System.out.println("uyuuuu"+threadSet);
         
    }

    private static void doTask3() {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(3);
        }

    }

    public  void dfo() {
         System.out.println("In main");      
         ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);     
         CompletableFuture<Void> thenCompose =CompletableFuture.allOf(
                 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doTask1()),
                 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doTask2(2)),
                 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doTask3()));
                
        
         //executor.shutdown();    
         try {
             Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
             System.out.println(threadSet);

            thenCompose.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         System.out.println("Exiting main");
         Set<Thread> threadSeWt = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
         System.out.println(threadSeWt);
    }
    private  void doTask2(int num) {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("4");
        }

    }

    private  int doTask1() {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5001);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(1);
        }
        return 5;

    }
}
```

`

Sample Output:

```
 [Thread[Finalizer,8,system], Thread[Attach Listener,5,system], Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system], Thread[Reference Handler,10,system], Thread[main,5,main]]
In main
[Thread[Finalizer,8,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main], Thread[main,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main], Thread[Attach Listener,5,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main], Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system], Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]]
431413431431431Exiting main
[Thread[Finalizer,8,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main], Thread[main,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main], Thread[Attach Listener,5,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main], Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system], Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]]
uyuuuu[Thread[Finalizer,8,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main], Thread[main,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main], Thread[Attach Listener,5,system], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main], Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system], Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]]
```

Comment: That’s the point of a *pool*, to keep them alive and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

The executor in your `dfo()` method is not used.

When you use `runAsync()` method, it runs on the common pool. That's why you see `ForkJoinPool` in your debug messages.

The size of that pool is limited by default by "number of your CPU cores - 1".

Try running 20 tasks, and you'll see that your thread count stops growing, once it reaches the maximum.

You don't need to stop the threads of the ForkJoinPool. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

> its threads are slowly reclaimed during periods of non-use

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, I have not used Executor intentionally to check behavior of Fork join pool.
I wanted to know why my thread are still showing active and what should i do to close them?
What if i recall the method dfo() again or thrice, then they create new thread or reusing the old one?

Comment: You don't need to close them. You can invoke `dfo()` method multiple times, and you'll see that the number of threads stops growing, because the maximum size of the pool has been reached.